# OSMF Flex examples

Tags: apache-flex, flash, osmf

Are there any examples on how to use the code found in the OSM framework in Flex? I would also need the player to be skinnable (hopefully by CSS).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rblank.com/category/code-and-samples/

http://www.osmf.org/developers.html

http://www.adobe.ca/devnet/flash/articles/reops_pt1.html